# Sqoop functionality has been removed from DSE

Tags: mysql, cassandra, sqoop, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am new to cassandra. Here I am tring to transfer whole my MYSQL database to cassandra using sqoop. But after all setup, when i execute following command.

```
bin/dse sqoop import-all-tables -m 1 --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/ABCDatabase --username root --password root --cassandra-thrift-host localhost --cassandra-create-schema --direct
```

I have received following error.

> Sqoop functionality has been removed from DSE.

It said that sqoop functionality is removed from datastax. can you please if it removed then is there any other way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spark to transfer data - it should be easy, something like:

```
val table = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "table", connectionProperties)
table.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(
   Map("table" -> "TBL", "keyspace" -> "KS")).save()
```

Examples of jdbc URLs, options, etc. are described in [Databrick's documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html) as they could be different for different databases.

Comment: I am new to spark and Java but little bit know python. can you please provide me blog links which help me to execute your command with help of python? Thanks

Comment: Just read first several pages of Spark SQL documentation  - it has examples for python. Spark Cassandra connector documentation also has a section on python

Comment: as per you documentation url, I have successfully connected to MySql and cassandra with help of spark. but now everytime i need to transfer only newly added records. how to do that? is there any api support available?

Comment: That's depends on schema of your database - just use query that will select/filter only new records...

Comment: thank for you suggestion, but I am looking for another solution if any because I have around 500 tables and if I applied query base solution then it become to lengthy to manage.

Comment: I can only suggest to use another approach then - use Kafka Connect with corresponding connectors, so you capture the changes instead of fetching data from tables

Comment: thanks for direction, can you have any link, blog, tutorial which help me to sync data?

Comment: Look to Confluent's blog - they had several blog posts about that topic